# django htmx: como redirecionar para outra página?

Tags: django

Em meu projeto, estou trabalhando django + htmx e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

> depois que o usuário foi validado via post, como vou redirecionar a página por completo, sendo que o htmx faz um innerHtml?

Answer (score 0):

Então, em um post do reddit encontrei a seguinte solução [fonte](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/wwi2pu/htmx_and_user_login_time_out/iln8u0u/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button):

```py
def login_required_htmx(view): 
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            resp = HttpResponse('')
            resp['HX-Redirect'] = LOGIN_URL
            return resp
    return wrap
```

em uma implementação direta na view

```py
def nome_da_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return return render(...)
    else:
        resp = HttpResponse('')
        resp['HX-Redirect'] = LOGIN_URL
        return resp
```

sei que pode não ser a melhor e a mais adequada solução, mas funcionou pra mim. Caso alguém tenha uma resposta melhor, fico no aguardo para poder implementar.